# How do I combine terms in Drupal feeds?

Tags: feeds

For example if I had 2 rows with people in them

```
uid | favourite colour
----------------------
 3  | Blue
 3  | Yellow
```

And I wanted the result to have both Blue and Yellow selected at the end. Is there a combine tamper plugin? I am already doing

```
class MyAlterSubscriber extends AfterParseBase
```

Do I need to lookup existing values here and combine them first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AfterParseBase [does not give access to the full set of data](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/feeds/feeds-howtos/altering-feed-data).

Therefore, use the FeedsEvents::AFTER event instead.

I found that if the last item had no taxonomy items selected then all items would be lost. To create a union of taxonomy items:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\cbi_feed_alter\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\feeds\Event\FeedsEvents;
use Drupal\feeds\Event\ParseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class IssuerFeedEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  const JOIN_CHAR = ',';

  /**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[FeedsEvents::PARSE][] = ['afterParse', FeedsEvents::AFTER];
    return $events;
  }

  public function afterParse(ParseEvent $event) {
    /** @var \Drupal\feeds\FeedInterface */
    $feed = $event->getFeed();
    /** @var \Drupal\feeds\Result\ParserResultInterface */
    $parser_result = $event->getParserResult();

    $feed_type = $feed->getType();
    if ($feed_type->id() != 'issuer') {
      return;
    }

    for ($parser_result->rewind(); $parser_result->valid(); $parser_result->next()) {
      $this->findStates($parser_result->current(), $parser_result);
    }
  }

  protected function findStates($item, $parser_result) {
    $issuer_id = $item->get('issuerid');
    $states = [];
    $parser_current_key = $parser_result->key();
    for ($parser_result->rewind(); $parser_result->valid(); $parser_result->next()) {
      if ($parser_result->current()->get('issuerid') == $issuer_id) {
        $states = array_filter(array_merge($states, explode(self::JOIN_CHAR, $parser_result->current()->get('state'))));

     }
    }

    // Iterate back to the key
    $parser_result->rewind();
    while ($parser_result->valid() && $parser_result->key() != $parser_current_key) {
      $parser_result->next();
    }
    $parser_result->offsetSet($parser_current_key);
    $item->set('state', implode(self::JOIN_CHAR, array_unique($states, SORT_STRING)));
   }

}
```